# jQuery append after submitting with colorbox iframe

Tags: jquery, append, colorbox

if you could help me with the code below. For some reason, **its not appending** the row to table `#appendAffiliate` soon form submitted. I use colorbox as modal dialog.

Note: this only occurs when when submitting form in colorbox modal.

```
HTML:
<a href="page/frame.php" class="colorbox-iframe"></a>

frame.php FILE (modal):
<form>....</form>

table markup:
<table width="100%" id="appendAffiliate">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Discount</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.colorbox-iframe').colorbox({
 overlayClose: false,
 iframe: true,
 scrolling: false,
 innerWidth: 200,
 innerHeight:150
});

$('form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'json/json.php',
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
      if ( data.ok ) {

   // None working     
   $('#appendAffiliate').append('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');
   $('#appendAffiliate > tbody').append('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');        
   $('#appendAffiliate tbody:last').append('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');

        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);

        setTimeout(function(){
          $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',false);
          **parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();**             
        },2000);
      } else {

      }
     }
    });
   return false;
})
```

Comment: Are you certain that `id (data.ok)` evaluates true? I see there is nothing in the else clause, also no ajax failure callback.

Comment: @AshirvadSingh see updated content.

Comment: @DavidBarker else clause is just for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You should append to `thead`

CODE

```
$('#appendAffiliate thead').append('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Also check if it is going inside data.ok condition?

Comment: @Ashirwad, i guess it would be in tbody instead of thead

Answer (score 0):

Your posts don't clearly differentiate between what markup/js is in the parent form (the page that calls ColorBox) and what markup/js is in the content that ColorBox shows.

If the table is in the parent, be sure to refer to the parent when making the Append. (You might be trying to append to a node in the child page which may not exist.)